# select a Select option by text with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box and one string and i would select a option by string.
For example string="Volvo" and select box like this:

```html
 <select>
  <option value="v1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="v2">Saab</option>
  <option value="v3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="v4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you already tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 6):

Use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** pseudo-class selector to get option which contains certain string. And for updating checked property use **[`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method.

```js
$('option:contains("Volvo")').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="v1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="v2">Saab</option>
  <option value="v3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="v4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

---

For exact match use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method, since **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** not check for exact match.

```js
$('option').filter(function() {
  // check trimmed text for filtering 
  return $.trim($(this).text()) == "Mercedes";
}).prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="v1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="v2">Saab</option>
  <option value="v3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="v4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:contains` selector to achieve this:

```
var $option = $('select option:contains("Volvo")');
```

Or, to use a variable for the value:

```
var text = 'Volvo';
var $option = $('select option:contains("' + text + '")');
```

Alternatively you could use `filter()` to ensure an exact match on the required value:

```
var text = 'Volvo';
var $option = $('select option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == text;
});
```

From there you just need to set the `checked` property to `true`:

```
$option.prop('checked', true);
```